# Trigger EA plan when Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1 orders change status?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine, engagement-plans

I work with Sitecore 8.2 Update-5 and Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1. Is it possible to trigger an EA plan when an order is updated with a new status?

Let's say I want to trigger a EA plan that sends an email when an order status is changed to shipped. How can this be done? I havent find any event based documentation for this yet, so my idea is to implement some sort of api call from the Commerce Engine when the order status is changed to the Sitecore website instance.

Comment: By EA plan, are you saying Engagement Plans? If so, Engagement Plans have been removed from Sitecore 8.2 update -5 and are not accessible. If you are needing some kind of marketing automation, I would recommend moving to the latest version of Sitecore 9+ and utilize the Marketing Automation functionality.

Comment: @Pete Navara Are you sure about that? I cant find any documentation about it being removed in 8.2.u5. I can create EA plans in this version of Sitecore. I cant upgrade to Sitecore 9+ yet, it's on the roadmap but not for a year or so.